# 'Evaluation error' when using Aggregate tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, error, concatenation, aggregate

In QGIS 3.16. I am using the Aggregate function to reduce the number of features in a layer. I am grouping by one field and I want to concatenate the others.

My actual data table is fairly large and the operation seems to be working for some of my fields, but for some fields, I get an error message related to the concatenation, and for the life of me I can't figure out why.

Here is a screenshot of my Aggregate setup for a truncated version of my table, with a few of the features that are having problems. I am grouping by the field `"Complexe"`; note that all output field types are set to String (Text) with a length of 100, so that is not the issue:
[image]

This is the message that I get :
[image]

> Evaluation error in expression
> "concatenate("ID_CH","Complexe",TRUE,',')": Could not calculate
> aggregate for ID_CH. Execution failed after 0.86 seconds.

Here are the files if you'd like to try and reproduce the problem: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nOV1dxZWzNiIg9F77brQ36Rcvoze8QSb?usp=sharing

Comment: please do not put text in your question as an image - this makes it unreadable for many users (including Google)

Comment: Hi Ian, I used the native 'add picture' function.  Would it be better to post a link to the picture? Or is there another way of loading a picture onto SE?  Sorry for the newbie errors, I'll get the hang of it...

Comment: You should copy and paste the actual text into the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The string function raised `'Evaluation error'` because it couldn't parse the input.

To overcome it wrap each of your fields into the [`to_string()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#to-string) function in the *'Source Expression'*

[image: aggregate_window]

and get the output

[image: result]

Also mind the length of the output field.

Additionally, before aggregation I may suggest checking the validity of geometry of your features, e.g. with the ["Check Validity"](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#check-validity) or the ["Geometry Checker Plugin"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_geometry_checker.html#geometry-checker-plugin). Otherwise you will face similar issues as I had:

[image: geometry_1]
[image: geometry_2]

and others...

Comment: Simple and effective. Thanks for patiently helping me see what was right in front of me but which I hadn't noticed!  Also thanks for the plugin suggestions.

Comment: Always welcome!